# Finding correlation between multiple variables and a target value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I have an array of words, taken from a review of a hotel.
E.g

```
array(['advantage', 'advice', 'anniversary', 'arrived', 'aveda', 'bangs',
       'bath', 'bed', 'check', 'clean', 'closing', 'comfortable', 'deal',
       'did', 'disappointed', 'distance', 'doors', 'easy', 'evening',
       'existent', 'expensive', 'experience', 'goldfish', 'good', 'got',
       'great', 'hallway', 'having', 'hear', 'heard', 'high', 'hotel',
       'just', 'late', 'like', 'little', 'location', 'longer', 'loud',
       'maybe', 'morning', 'music', 'neck', 'neighbors', 'nice', 'night',
       'noisy', 'non', 'not', 'opening', 'overall', 'parking', 'pay',
       'people', 'pillows', 'previous', 'products', 'quick', 'reviews',
       'room', 'shopping', 'size', 'soundproof', 'stay', 'staying',
       'stiff', 'taken', 'talking', 'took', 'touch', 'valet', 'view',
       'walking', 'woke'], dtype='<U12')
```

Then I have the rating that the hotel was given for this review
e.g in this case the hotel received 4 stars.

I've got the same for around 20k reviews.

I'm looking to see try to find the correlation between the words and the review.

For example one might assume that reviews that have words like "Clean", "great", "liked", "recommend" would get a higher starred review than ones with "dirty", "disliked", "small", "disappointing"

I tried to approach this with pandas `corr` and `corrwith` functions and also using NumPy for calculating the correlation, but I couldn't get it working and producing a good outcome.

Comment: what do want exactly? what kind of output?

Comment: Well, ideally a score for each word that describes how they affect the rating.
For example, "dirty" could receive a -0.6, meaning it strongly lowers the rating.
(Normalized to -1-1, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no pandas expert, but i could offer a possible approach.
You could create a dict, where the key is a word and value is a list of stars of hotel that this word is related to.
Let's assume that your data is a list of dicts, that represent hotels and have at least these keys: score, words. Where score - is hotel score, words - your words data

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_rates = defaultdict(list())
for hotel in hotels:
    for word in hotel['words']:
        word_rates.append(hotel['score'])
```

Now you have scores per word, like this:

```
{
    'bad': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2],
    'great': [4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4],
    ...
}
```

It is up to you how to interpret it, but counting how good/bad scores are should give you a rough estimation.

Comment: I'm going to mark this the "correct" answer, since this is the one I ended up going with.
That being said If I could I would mark this and the answer from @agcala correct aswell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to come up with a code that would give each of the words **a rank from good to bad**, starting with the good adjective with lower rank up to the bad ones with higher rank.  I would start by sorting them and then giving them a numerical code that would reflect how good/bad a word is. **Note that not all words need to be given a code. In this case 0 would be okay.**

I'd start with something like

```
words.sort()
word_coded=dict([[x,0] for x in words])
```

will give you a dictionary

```
{'advantage': 0,
 'advice': 0,
 ......
 'bed': 0,
 'check': 0,
 'clean': 0,
 ...
 'comfortable': 0,
 'deal': 0,
 'did': 0,
 ...
 'disappointed': 0,
```

A dictionary would be more easy to work with than a list. Then I'd say, for example

```
 words_coded['advantage']=10
 ........
 words_coded['disappointed']=120
```

and so on. You will have to do this manually or come up with some sort of coding algorithm. Either way once you have your words ranked, you can use a **[non parametric correlation](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470905173.ch17)** like [**Spearman's**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html)  to find out your correlation coefficient.

**Spearman's correlation coefficient** assumes nothing as it only ranks the values and then uses the ranking to calculate correlation. On the other hand, **Pearson's assumes normal distribution of the variables and I wouldn't recommend it in this case.**

Answer (score 0):

`corr`and `corrwith`are designed for numerical columns. For your purpose have a look at:

> Forthmann, Boris. (2015). Re: Can I use Pearson’s correlation
> coefficient to know the relation between perception and gender, age,
> income?. Retrieved from:

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_I_use_Pearsons_correlation_coefficient_to_know_the_relation_between_perception_and_gender_age_income/567f17ed61432567d88b45e8/citation/download.

Comment: Pearson's correlation coefficient assumes normal distribution of the variables. I don't think that's true in this case.